# Jboss use JTS instead of JTA

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, jta, distributed-transactions, jts

I have jacorb subsystem enabled in my jboss. But JTS is not enabled, I use only JTA.

When an EJB remote call received by the jboss, instead of using JTA(com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.jca.TransactionImporterImple) it gets JTS(com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.jca.TransactionImporterImple) and proceed with JTS. Since JTS is not enabled it failed with ORB is not initialized error. Can you please help me to identify why JTS is used instead of JTA.

```
JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component TestBean for method public abstract java.lang.Object com.subhash.test.TestBean.processWithResults(com.subhash.test.Test) throws com.subhash.test.testException: com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.FatalError

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jts.ORBManager.getPOA(ORBManager.java:96)

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jts.orbspecific.ControlImple.createTransactionHandle(ControlImple.java:524)

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jts.orbspecific.interposition.ServerControl.<init>(ServerControl.java:223)

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.subordinate.jca.SubordinateAtomicTransaction.<init>(SubordinateAtomicTransaction.java:51)

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.subordinate.jca.TransactionImple.<init>(TransactionImple.java:57)

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.jca.TransactionImporterImple.addImportedTransaction(TransactionImporterImple.java:233)

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.jca.TransactionImporterImple.importRemoteTransaction(TransactionImporterImple.java:90)

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.jca.TransactionImporterImple.importTransaction(TransactionImporterImple.java:70)

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionsRepository.importTransaction(EJBRemoteTransactionsRepository.java:187) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.createOrResumeXidTransaction(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:126) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:72) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.3.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:189) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-1]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:327) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:69) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:202) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.21.Final-redhat-1-bz-1653367.jar:7.5.21.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]

at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_202]

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_202]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_202]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_202]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_202]

at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Comment: here is important to know how you configure the EJB remote call. Can you provide information what is the EJB remoting address the remote call aims to? What are the descriptors you use to configure the JBoss/WildFly to run this remote call?

Comment: Hi @chalda, thank for your reply,.I use the receiver ip address for remote call. This is purely intermittent and as explained in the previous issue it is even observed during startup.

Comment: I think the issue is the transactionManagerClassName defined in the JtaEnviornmentBean is updated with wrong JTS impl.

Comment: hi @Subhashc. Ok, I see and understand your point. The point is that Narayana is started with default configuration which is taken from `jbossts-properties.xml` file. At WildFly startup that could be changed with WildFly subsystem setup. If the transaction subsystem is delayed and the transaction is imported before configuration is finished then I assume this error.
From the error message it seems that the error comes from the transaction import. That means other server calls this particular server and this one fails as it's not capable to handle incoming call.

Comment: From that I understand it's not about how the remote call is configured but when the incoming call hits the server. Still if you use the JBoss AS 7, it's an old version of the container and the best would be to move to some newer WildFly version and verify if the same error could be observed.

Comment: Configuration of the `xml` configuration file is here: https://github.com/jbosstm/narayana/blob/master/ArjunaJTS/narayana-jts-idlj/src/main/resources/jbossts-properties.xml#L147

Comment: Hi @chalda I really appreciate your replies,

1. Yes, Narayana is starting with the default configuration.
2. We have seen this error in two situations,
A. During the EJB call - I have pasted the stack trace in the description and as you said it has happened during transaction import

Comment: B. During wildfly start up - as part of periodic recovery, below is the stacktrace,
    @JBOSS@WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA012087: Activate of atomic action with id 0:ffff0af7f64f:-2cf6120f:5e408f8d:3f95e and type /StateManager/BasicAction/TwoPhaseCoordinator/ArjunaTransactionImple/ServerTransaction/JCA unexpectedly failed, could not load state.
    @JBOSS@FATAL [com.arjuna.ats.jts] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA022006: The ORB has not been initialized yet

Comment: @JBOSS@ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) Exception in thread "Periodic Recovery" com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.FatalError
    @JBOSS@ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) #011at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jts.ORBManager.getPOA(ORBManager.java:96)
    @JBOSS@ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) #011at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jts.orbspecific.ControlImple.createTransactionHandle(ControlImple.java:524)
    @JBOSS@ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) #011at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jts.orbspecific.interposition.ServerControl.<init>(ServerControl.java:223)

Comment: @JBOSS@ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) #011at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.subordinate.jca.SubordinateAtomicTransaction.<init>(SubordinateAtomicTransaction.java:71)
    @JBOSS@ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) #011at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.subordinate.jca.TransactionImple.<init>(TransactionImple.java:70)
    @JBOSS@ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) #011at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.jca.TransactionImporterImple.recoverTransaction(TransactionImporterImple.java:98)

Comment: @JBOSS@ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) #011at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.SubordinateAtomicActionRecoveryModule.periodicWorkFirstPass(SubordinateAtomicActionRecoveryModule.java:73)
    @JBOSS@ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) #011at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:765)
    @JBOSS@ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) #011at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:377)

Comment: From both the stacktrace we could see that jboss is processing with 'com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.jca.TransactionImporterImple.recoverTransaction' (JTS). Where it suppose to go with 'com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.jca.TransactionImporterImple' (JTA). We have not enabled JTS in standalone file.
The above TransactionImporterImple is decided using the below logic, not sure why it is getting JTS.

Comment: private static TxType guessTxType() {
        TransactionManager tm = com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager();
        
        if(tm instanceof com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple)
        {
            return TxType.JTA;
        } else if (tm.getClass().getName().contains(".jts.") || tm.getClass().getName().contains(".jtax.")) {
            return TxType.JTS;
        } else {
            return TxType.JTA;
        }
    }
code:  groupId:org.jboss.jbossts artifactId: jbossjts

Comment: hi @Subhashc. I think your suspicion is correct about the `guessTxType`. But again the reason could be various. There could be an issue in subsystem configuration or some race condition. But you use the old JBoss AS 7.x app server. If you don't confirm it's the issue of the new WildFly release then I think I can't help you too much.
The JBoss AS uses the jacorb subsystem and now WildFly uses the openjdk iiop. The subsystem configuration changed a lot.
I tried to run the `remote-ejb` quickstart which runs the ejb calls from a client to server. I run it in loop,

Comment: hitting it with several instances. Meanwhile I was restarting the server. And I could not replicate you issue.

Comment: The only thing more on top of what we discussed is that it would be nice to know how have you configured the `transactions` field in the jacorb subsystem?
https://wildscribe.github.io/JBoss%20AS7/7.1.1/subsystem/jacorb/index.html#attr-transactions
Is that set for `off`?

Comment: Hi @chalda
we have defined jacord as below

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jacorb:1.4">
            <orb name="${instance-name}" socket-binding="jacorb" ssl-socket-binding="jacorb-ssl">
                <initializers security="identity" transactions="spec"/>
            </orb>
            <naming root-context="${instance-name}/Naming/root"/>
            <properties>
                <property name="jacorb.poa.thread_pool_max" value="50"/>
            </properties>
        </subsystem>

Comment: and transaction as
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.5">
            <core-environment node-identifier="${jboss.tx.node.id}">
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
As we are not using JTS we are removing jacorb subsystem and all its references. We don't see any other action item than.this.

Comment: and after removing the `jacorb` subsystem you can still see the error or it's fixed by that change?

Comment: we have not delivered the changes, it is in progress and the issue itself is intermittent. We are also enabling TRACE log for com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.jca package.
In this way we can see when the TxType is set in com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.jca.SubordinationManager